# Maze solver using graph traversal algorithms

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

In my class I have an assignment directed as follows:

In this lab, you will implement a Maze Solver, using a variety of graph-search algorithms.

Implement a templated Graph data structure, implementing the following functionality:

```
Add Node
Add Adjacency (given node, and adjacent node)
Breadth-First Search
Depth-First Search
Dijkstra’s Shortest Path Algorithm
```

To evaluate this data structure, write a program that reads a data file (with the filename passed as a command line parameter) and populates the data structure.

A set of mazes will be provided in doc sharing.
Maze Data Format
The maze data files will be text files containing integers.
The first line gives the size of the maze, in ‘cells’, x first, then y, separated by a space.

The second line gives the coordinates of the ‘start’ of the maze (x, then y, separated by a space)

The third line gives the coordinates of the ‘end’ of the maze (x, then y, separated by a space

The remainder of the file is a grid of numbers the size of the maze, space separated, where each number represents an ‘open’ (0) or ‘closed’(1) cell. Your ‘player’ can move into open cells, but not closed cells.

For various provided mazes, evaluate the execution time of each algorithm and the final path length (number of nodes opened to find the path). Record this data, by dataset size (total number of cells in the maze).

First, I don't even know how to implement a graph in the first place. All the reference that I can find just tells me what a graph is but not how to even start coding it. Do I create a class or struct like in a linked list or tree? I have no idea on what I am supposed to do.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#include <list>
#include <map>
#include <queue>

template <typename T>
class Graph
{
  T V; //vertices

  list<T> *adj; //edges;

public:
  Graph(T V); //constructor
  void addEdge(T v, T w); //function to add an edge to the graph
  void BFS(T s); //prints the bfs traversal

};

Graph(T V)
{
  this->V = V;
  adj = new list<T>[V];
}

void Graph::addEdge(T v, T w)
{
  adj[v].push_back(w); //Add w to v's list
}

void Graph::BFS(T s)
{
  //Mark all the vertices as not visited
  bool *visited = new bool[V];

  for (int i - 0; i<V; i++)
    visited[i] = false;

  // create a queue for BFS
  list<int>queue;

  //Mark the current node as visited and enque it

  visited[s] = true;
  queue.push_back(s);

  //i  will be used to get all adjacent vertices of a vertex

  list<T>::iterator i;

  while (!queue.empty())
  {
    //deque a vertex from queue and print it
    s = queue.front();

    cout << s << " ";
    queue.pop_front();

    for (i = adj[s].begin(); i != adj[s].end(); i++)
    {
      if (!visited[*i])
      {
        visited[*i] = true;
        queue.push_back();

      }
    }
  }
}
```

Please excuse the formatting as I never used this site and I dont know how to properly place a block of code

Comment: Googling for `undirected graph implementation c++` gave me [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/20184/undirected-connected-and-weighted-graph-implementation) (linked data structure) and [this](http://www.algolist.net/Data_structures/Graph/Internal_representation) (adjacency list/matrix). These are the common implementations (the first is simpler, the other two are more performance efficient due to spatial locality.

Comment: Do you know how to implement a linked list or tree? Are you familiar with the STL containers like `std::vector` and `std::list`?

Comment: @Beta I have implemented a linked list and a tree before one time each for a school assignment. I do think that I have a fairly decent grasp of trees and linked lists. I went on a tutoring site and I got some help but it is not nearly enough and I dont have the money to continue with the tutoring.

Comment: What you "have so far" doesn't compile, and appears highly confused. If you write a lot of code, attempting new things, and then try to run it, you're sure to fail; you must start small and simple, then build up, testing at every step.

Comment: This is exactly what the tutor showed me and I thought I had understood what was going on but evidently I was wrong. The online school that I am attending has the classes formatted into 5 week courses. So for this Junior/Senior level class of Data structures and algorithms I have taken 1 5 week calculus course and 2 5-week c++ programming courses. That is the absolute extent of my preparation for this course and I feel that I have not been sufficiently prepared for coding of this level.

Comment: Yes, you are in deep water, but we can help. As Leeor says, you implement a graph as a linked structure or as an adjacency matrix. Which do you prefer?

Comment: the data files that we have to read appears to provide a adjacency matrix. does that mean I have to implement it that way?

Comment: No, you don't have to. Choose the design you feel most comfortable with.

Comment: My instructor just gave me this link [link](http://www.cs.uah.edu/~rcoleman/Common/CodeVault/Code/Code301_Graphs.html)  for some reference. It shows using an adjacency matrix so maybe that is what he wants.